# iOS MapKit with less details

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, dictionary, mapkit

I have an iPhone/iPad application that displays the mapkit and adds other informations on top of it using annotations/overlays.
The problem is that the standard information presented already on the map, especially the road ids, disturb the users and they hardly see some of the information we present using annotations.
We have users asking us to remove as much from the map details and to display only our information, which they are interesting in, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Can some of the information from the Standard MapKit type be removed somehow?

Thanks,
Bogdan.

Comment: You could use the Satellite type, there are no info about id roads etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set `mapType` to `mutedStandard`

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.mapType = .mutedStandard
}
```